# Perforce Depot - Cannot delete depot

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I cannot delete my stream Depot even though I've deleted all the streams of it. I tried the solution listed here: https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2546 but it didn't work. Please help.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> p4 streams //test/...
//test/... - no such stream.
PS C:\Users\xxxx> p4 depot -d -f test
Depot 'test' is the location of existing streams; cannot delete until they are removed.
```

Comment: Does `p4 streams` (no arguments) list any streams that start with `//test`?

Comment: Just tried, no streams start with //test

Comment: Feels like it might be a db inconsistency.  Contacting Perforce support would be best, but if you want to debug it yourself, I’d start by taking a checkpoint and grepping it for `//test`.  Maybe a stream was only partially deleted and there are fragments of it in the db blocking the depot deletion?

Comment: Thanks! I looked into the db files but still no luck. I will contact the support team. Will post here if I found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, here are the steps I took to delete the depot successfully:

1. delete all the related workspaces
2. obliterate the streams
3. delete streams:

   - When you delete the streams from P4V, what gets executed is "p4 obliterate -y -T //testDepot/...", which won't actually delete the streams
   - Run "p4 streams -a" in the shell and you will see the streams which are marked as "delete"
   - Run "p4 stream --obliterate -y  //testDepot/main" allows you to actually delete the stream (the main stream in this example)
4. Finally, you'll be able to delete the depot after all the streams are deleted.

Comment: halleluyah, just needed the `-a` flag in p4 streams... damn